# How does mysql import from dump file work at the program level?

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

We can import a dump created using `mysqldump`using the following command:

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

I wish to know how does mysql process the dump file, is there some standardized schema or code for parsing sqldump files, or does mysql use its own specialized format?

I am sure there must be some specialized parser built for mysql which parses the commands, or the file. I am interested in knowing of that parser has been implemented in other languages, so that someone can parse mysql files, or even full dump files.

My second question: Are there some implementations of mysql parser (at the file level) in other languages. More specifically, I am interested in knowing if the `INSERT INTO TABLE "tbl_name" VALUES` format can be correctly and efficiently parsed, possibly in a streaming fashion for large dump files.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqldump file.sql is a raw set of SQL statement. They are parsed by the server mysqld.

While these are easy to read, parsing them isn't implemented elsewhere.

For a flexible format to use with other programs, look at CSV. `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` as an example of generating a csv file from a query.